# What is a Macho Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Macho Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Macho Word™ | Not a Macho Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| SEARCH | QUEST |
| FRENCH | SPANISH |
| JOKE | HUMOR |
| ABROAD | DOMESTIC |
| EARL | BARON |
| AMERICAN | YANKEE |
| GHOUL | SPECTER |
| DHOW | JUNK |
| SEMITIC | HEBREW |
| ABACUS | PROTRACTOR |

Here is the CSV version:

```
Macho Word™, Not a Macho Word™
SEARCH, QUEST
FRENCH, SPANISH
JOKE, HUMOR
ABROAD, DOMESTIC
EARL, BARON
AMERICAN, YANKEE
GHOUL, SPECTER
DHOW, JUNK
SEMITIC, HEBREW
ABACUS, PROTRACTOR
```

Hint 1:

> Have you ever studied oceanography?

Hint 2:

> The puzzle has nothing to do with oceanography as a scientific discipline, it's a reference to something.

Hint 3:

> *Where* can you study oceanography?

Comment: A real stretch but.... rot13(frrvat gur gvgyr, gur pubvpr bs jbeqf, naq gur uvag... Vf guvf n wbwb'f ersrerapr?)

Comment: @Belhenix no it isn't.

Comment: Not getting anywhere too far, but does the solution involve rot13(Vfynaqf?  [Znpub - >  Zna -> Vfyr bs Zna] naq [Bprnabtencul vf orfg fghqvrq ba vfynaqf])

Comment: @TwoBitOperation no, you're on the wrong track.

Comment: Could we get another clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Macho Word is:

> **A word in which the first 2 letters are the initials of a Village People member.**
>
>  'Macho' alludes to their song '[Macho Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo5o_R8txUo)', while 'study oceanography' alludes to the lyrics of their song '[In The Navy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj9tMqgEGLA)' (*"Play in sports and skin dive/Study oceanography..."*)
>
>  The group had many reincarnations, resulting in a [long list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Village_People#Lineup) of past and present members. And after going over all of them [thanks for the exhaustive lesson in V.P. history, BTW ;)], I can confirm that all Macho Words begin with a V.P. member's initials while the Non-Macho Words do not. The members that match the examples are: Sonny Earl (**SE**), Felipe Rose (**FR**), Jeff Olson (**JO**), Alex Briley (**AB**), Eric Anzalone (**EA**), Angel Morales (**AM**), Glenn Hughes (**GH**) and David Hodo (**DH**).